# Can I use log4j in Java and log4cxx in C++ in a JNI project to store log in the same file?

Tags: logging, java-native-interface, log4j, log4cxx, log4cpp

I am writing a non Android JNI program, and the java side is using log4j for logging. Can I use log4cxx or log4cpp on the C++ side and share the same config as java, so that the native log will be stored in the same file? Are there any downside of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not work as intended depending on how complicated your config file is.  For example, you could potentially have an issue where your file rolls over, and things could get out of sync between the log4cxx side and the log4j side.

The secondary problem that you may have is that log4cxx and log4j2 use different config file formats; this would only work if you use log4j 1.x.

What I have done in the past is to simply create a logger inside of the class that I will call from the JNI code; this solves the issue by always using a Java logger even from inside the JNI code.  The downside is that this won't work if your JNI code is very complex.  [Here](https://github.com/rm5248/jni-utils) is a project that I created a while ago with some utility functions to help perform this task which may help you to get started.